# Find out the data type of a column in SQL with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, sqldatatypes

I need to change a column that is integer to decimal in an SQL table.

I think that before making such a change, I should find out if the change has been made before, for which Im executing the following code:

```js
var varx = context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SELECT COLUMN_NAME = 'column_name' FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where DATA_TYPE = 'decimal' AND TABLE_NAME = 'table_name'");
```

But regardless of whether the column is already decimal or still integer, varx is equal to -1 always

Any suggestions or comments are welcome.

Comment: Have you ran the select by itself, what does it produce? Also `SELECT COLUMN_NAME = 'column_name'` isn't doing what you think it's doing; hence why it's returning `-1` as no rows were affected. Maybe `SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where DATA_TYPE = 'decimal' AND TABLE_NAME = 'table_name'`.The query itself is wrong, but not sure still what you want, can you clarify in better details?

Comment: why you want to do this with EntityFramework ? Do you have a DB-First or Code-First database. Changing the Datatype on a Code-First Database is a completly different thing, and with SQL-commands you rather destroy the migration integrity.

Comment: I want to do it because I have a whole project in Visual Studio done with EntityFramework, but I already made it. I already publish my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a solution:

```js
int n = context.Database.SqlQuery<int>("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where DATA_TYPE = 'int' AND TABLE_NAME = 'my_table' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'column name'").ToList().FirstOrDefault();
```

n is equal to 1 if there is an int type element in the table and if there isn't, it is zero.

Answer (score 0):

If you can connect to Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, you can look to the left of the window, in object explorer, go to the table you are looking to alter, expand it, and on the columns folder you can see all the columns and their types.

Or, as @Çöđěxěŕ said you could execute that query by itself first and see what it actually returns